# Ajax Json Youtube API Error for contentDetails

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have an ajax json script that works just fine, however I get an error in the console.

```
//load youtube videos to game page
function loadGameVideos(){
    var formData = {
        'game_platform_link' : $('.game_platform_link').attr('name'),
        'game_title_link' : $('.game_title_link').attr('name')
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/games/videos_get.php',
        data : formData,
        dataType : 'json',
        beforeSend: function(){
          $(".bbox_content.bbox_videos").append("<div class='content_loader_container'><span class='content_loader'><img src='/images/loader.gif'></div>");   
        },
        success: function(viddata) {
            $.each(viddata.videos, function(i, video){
                $.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos", {
                    key: "AIzaSyAQ26GN-L4JyAcuwOdWRgLLvGNG1uh5g6k",
                    part: "snippet,contentDetails,statistics",
                    id: video
                }, function(data) {
                    var duration = convert_time(data.items[0].contentDetails.duration);
                    var views = data.items[0].statistics.viewCount.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                    $(".bbox_content.bbox_videos .content_loader_container").remove(); 
                    $(".bbox_content.bbox_videos").append($('<div class="bbox_item bbox_video_item"><a class="video_item youtube" href="/video/' + video + '" style="background-image:url('+ data.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.high.url +');"><span class="img"><img width="100%" src="/images/movie_arrow.png"/></span><span class="video_time">'+ duration +'</span></a><div class="bbox_video_item_info"><span class="video_title">'+ data.items[0].snippet.title +'</span><span class="view_count">Views: '+ views +'</span></div></div>').hide().fadeIn(800));
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The error is as follows.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentDetails' of undefined

Everything is working, I just don't like having the error lol. Anyone know why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
//if you test get json call

$.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos", {
    key: "AIzaSyAQ26GN-L4JyAcuwOdWRgLLvGNG1uh5g6k",
    part: "snippet,contentDetails,statistics",
    id: 'G_0TziI12SE'
}, function (data) {

    console.log(data.items[0].contentDetails);

});

//contentDetails success returned value

//check your video id callback on this line 'id: video'
```